# Pointer to blog posts does not contain the replies that belong to the post (Parse, Swift, iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, relationship, relationships

I am working on a social iPhone app using Swift (with a Storyboard) and Parse where users can create posts and reply/comment on posts.

I am trying to create a relationship between a post and the comments that belong to it (ie: A one-to-many relationship where a post (parent) has one or more comments (child)).

This is the structure of the Parse data browser.

**Post table:**
[image]

**Reply table:**
[image]

When a user comments/replies on a post, the Reply table shows which post was commented on (the post's objectId from the Post table is shown in the post column of the Reply table (which is a a pointer to the Post object: post Pointer).

However, the reply column in the Post table (which is a pointer to the Reply table) does not show the replies that belong to the post. It's supposed to populate all the replies (reply objectIds) that were made for a given post but is not showing...Why? I appreciate your help!

Note: When a user types a comment in the textfield and presses "Send", a relationship is created when I set the post that this comment belongs to:

```
var postObject: PFObject?
...
@IBAction func sendCommentButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
  var myComment = PFObject(className: "Reply")
  ...
  myComment["post"] = postObject
  ...
}
```

Now, I am not sure *how and where* to create the relationship to set the comment(s) to the post that is being commented on...

Comment: Rename the reply column to replies, and define it as an Array instead and then append pointers to your Reply objects to this array

Answer (score 0):

You may want to watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x70G_LPlW60) Parse video. Reply belongs to a Post while Post doesn't have to belong to a reply.
Plus, theres a whole bunch of information about the subject available

Comment: yep, I watched that video before. It helped me set the post that a comment belongs to. However, it does not show how to set the comment(s) that a post has. I want to be able to store all the comments that were made for a post, keep track of the number of comments that a post has, etc.

Comment: This is bidirectional relationship. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740011/how-does-parse-com-create-a-bidirectional-relationship-in-the-ios-client Dig a little it will become apparent